# How to get an array of all the child elements using Dart Language?

Tags: dart, dart-webui, dart-editor

How to get the class names of the child elements of the class carousel in dart in the form of an array??

```html
<div class="carousel">
      <div class="galleryCars">
      ....
      </div>
      <div class="galleryCars2">
      ....
      </div>
      <div class="galleryCars3">
      ....
      </div>
      <div class="galleryCars4">
      ....
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick n dirty:

```dart
var carousel = query(".carousel");
var classList = [];
carousel.children.forEach((childElement) => classList.addAll(childElement.classes));
print(classList); // [galleryCars,galleryCars2,galleryCars3,galleryCars4]
```

Comment: Whats that 's' used for?? Is that 'e' or 's'?

Comment: I tried this method but its not printing or alerting the class names. I am new to dart and couldnt find the problem.

Comment: I've created a gist with the files I'm using here: https://gist.github.com/chrisbu/6268607 - the Dart `print()` statement goes back to the dart editor or console rather than appearing in the browser UI (print is like log messages)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to get a [Set](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Set.html) of children class names :

```dart
query('.carousel').children.expand((e) => e.classes).toSet();
```

Comment: I like your answer better :)